# How to get deferred object for sharepoint rest queries

Tags: jquery, rest

I want to create one common jquery library to work with REST queries in sharepoint. 
I have two files.

> 1. REST_Operations.js
> 2. consumer.js

In REST_Operations.js I am writing rest queries with deferred object as follows.

```
"use strict";
var RESTQueries = RESTQueries || {};
RESTQueries.getItemsFromList = function(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var execute = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"https://mysiteurl/sites/practice/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/items",
            method:'GET',
            headers:{Accept:'application/json; odata=verbose'},
            success:function(data){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            },
            error:function(err){
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
        });
        return deferred;
    };

    return {
        execute:execute
    }
}();

RESTQueries.readItemsFromList = function(){
    RESTQueries.getItemsFromList.execute().promise().then(function(data){
        return data;    
    });

}
```

If i put console.log in `then()` function, data is coming properly.
I have one more js file, `cosumer.js`, in that i am calling `readItemsFromList` as follows

```
var items = RESTQueries.readItemsFromList();
```

so my idea is `items` variable should contain the json object or result for the rest query. 
But if i put `console.log(items)`, output is coming as `undefined`.
How to get the json object in the `items` variable?

If I try with following code

```
RESTQueries.readItemsFromList = function(siteUrl,listName){
    return (RESTQueries.getItemsFromList.execute(siteUrl,listName).promise().then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
           return data; 
    }));
}
```

it is giving me different kind of object. Find the below screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add `return` in front off `RESTQueries.getItemsFromList`, like this:

```
RESTQueries.readItemsFromList = function(){
    return RESTQueries.getItemsFromList.execute().promise().then(function(data){
        return data;    
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion. I am trying to get like this `var items= RESTQueries.readItemsFromList()` but return item is giving some different kind of object, and if i put `console.log` inside of then function, this statement was executed after the items object. see my edited question for output

Comment: The object you get back is the promise, not the data. It's not synchronous, so you would do something like `RESTQueries.readItemsFromList().then(function(data) { console.log(data); });`

Comment: Yeah here I am getting data without any issues. My intention is make all queries as library. So finally people should write a single line of code as `var items = RESTQueries.readItemsFromList();`. People should not worry about the promises. You got what I am saying!!

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `$.ajax({async:false})` and drop promises. While that is possible, IMHO it's a bad idea. Returning a promise is a good thing, even if it adds some lines to the library usage. E.g., what would you do if you wanted to bundle several requests and wait for all of them to finish? With a promise that is superdupereasy

Comment: Yeah understood. actually i got it work like `RESTQueries.getItemsFromList.execute('https://mysiteurl/sites/practice','Pages').then(function(data){console.log(data);});` But I am just searching is there any way like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have one question, you are developing for APP in office 365 ?

If yes, continue reading the post. If not, explain to me how you want to do that maybe will help you :)

I'm sure you must put the AJAX that runs synchronously.

try with this code below:

```
"use strict";

var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var AppUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
var par_url, par_list; // parameters to set in ajax;
function getItemsFromList(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
            url: String.format("{0}/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('{1}')/items?@target='{3}'", AppUrl, par_list, par_url); 
            method:'GET',
            headers:{Accept:'application/json; odata=verbose'},
            success:function(data){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            },
            error:function(err){
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
        });
        return deferred;

};

function readItemsFromList(url, page){
  var scriptbase = hostUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
  // allow cross-domain between host and app!
  $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", function () {
    par_url = url;
    par_page = page;
    var processGETitems = new getItemsFromList();
    processGETitems.done(function (result) {
            return result;
    });
    processGETitems.fail(function (result) {
            return result;
    });
  });   
}


function getQueryStringParameter(urlParameterKey) {
    var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split('=');
        if (singleParam[0] == urlParameterKey) return decodeURIComponent(singleParam[1]);
    }
}
```

And now, you can call the method:

```
var items = getItemsFromList('http://yourdomain.com','ListName'); //return [Object] if not, maybe your url or list not exist.
```

Please let know if I helped you.

Thanks, 
b1c10

References:
http://weshackett.com/2014/02/sp-requestexecutor-cross-domain-calls-using-rest-gotcha/

> Note: If you use domain sphost different of hosturl that you set, you
>   will get acess denied  by security do Office 365 ! :/